# Does the authenticate method in the User class work?

Tags: authentication

This doesn't work:

```
$user = User::find()->email("bob@example.com")->one();
if ($user->authenticate("myClearTextPassword")) {
  // This is never true, so you never get here
}
```

Is this method broken, or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: What does `$user->authError` return after you call the authenticate method?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @BradBell. I get `invalid_credentials`, even when the password is correct.

Comment: Is the user in a soft-deleted state? Or do you have https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#preventuserenumeration set to `true`?

Comment: @BradBell I can confirm that this is not working still in 3.7.38.  preventUserEnumeration has not been set and should be defaulted to false.